# Which way should I compile my C code?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I have three files, test.c, foo.c, foo.h.
In foo.c i

```
#include "foo.h"
```

In test.c i

```
#include "foo.c."
```

Then when I compile my code, I use gcc -o test test.c, and it compiles.

However, my professor told me, I should use

```
#include "foo.h"
```

inside my test.c rather than `#include foo.c`, and I should compile it this way

```
gcc -o test test.c foo.c
```

Is the second way more preferred? If it is, why? What's the difference between these two compilation?

Comment: simple is try: `make` command

Comment: But I would like to understand what's going on under make. Isn't the purpose of learning low-level languages like C?

Comment: No [make](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm) utility use to compile source code(any language).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases you should never include source files (apart from cases where you would probably want to include a piece of code generated dynamically by a separate script). Source files are to be passed directly to the compiler. Only header files should be included.

Although the way that your professor suggests is correct, the following way has more educational value in this case:

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -o test foo.o test.o
```

The first two lines compile each source file to an object file, and the third line doesn't really compile but only invokes the linker to produce an executable out of the 2 object files. The idea is to make a distinction between *compiling* and *linking*, which would be performed transparently in the way your professor suggests.

Comment: Although, when it comes to `template` in C++, you **have to** either include CXX file in headers or write implementations directly into header. That is one nasty side of C++.

Comment: This question is tagged c not c++.

Comment: Sorry, but What will gcc -o foo.o test.o produce? An executable named a? Can I use gcc -o test foo.o test.o? Other than that, thanks for your thorough explanation!

Comment: @octref: Yes, the default executable name is `a.out`, even though it could be in an ELF format.

Comment: "What will gcc -o foo.o test.o produce?" Be careful with the -o flag ... that would put an executable into foo.o, which is a mistake (if the link succeeded which it wouldn't because it needs foo.o as an input).

Comment: "you have to either include CXX file in headers or write implementations directly into header" -- Not relevant to a C question, but putting a template implementation into a file with a .cxx extension and then including that is still writing implementations directly into the header, but misnaming it. The point remains: only include header files, not source files ... even in C++ with templates.

Comment: @phoeagon, you **never** `#include` a `.c` or `.cxx` file. The templates are defined in headers (and those don't carry extensions in today's C++ style).

Comment: @octref, by ancient convention, if you call the compiler to link an executable and don't give it a name, it is called `a.out`.

Comment: @octref `gcc -o foo.o test.o` will produce an executable named `foo.o` by linking `test.o` alone, which will fail because you will not be linking `foo.o`. If you meant `gcc -o test foo.o test.o` then it will produce an executable named `test`. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options): *"-o file    Write output to file."*

Answer (score 2):

The *major* reasons not to `#include` .c files in other .c files are:

- Avoid duplicate definition errors: suppose `foo.c` defines the function `foo()`.  You have two other files that use `foo()`, so you `#include "foo.c"` in both of them.  When you try to build your project, the compiler will translate `foo.c` multiple times, meaning it will see multiple attempts to define the `foo` function, which will cause it to issue a diagnostic and halt.
- Minimize build times: even if you don't introduce duplicate definition errors, you wind up recompiling the same code needlessly.  Suppose you `#include "foo.c"` in `bar.c`, and you discover you need to make a one-line change in `bar.c`.  When you rebuild, you wind up re-translating the contents of `foo.c` *unnecessarily*.

C allows you to compile your source files separately of each other, and then link the resulting object files together to build your applications or libraries.  Ideally, header files should only contain non-defining object declarations, function prototype declarations, type definitions, and macro definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to `#include` header files instead of source files, and compile source files individually. Separation of concerns makes it easier to work with in large projects. In your example, it may be trivial, but could be confusing when you have hundreds of files to work with.

Doing it the way your professor suggests means you can compile each source separately. So, if you had a large project where the sources were thousands of lines of code, and you changed something in `test.c`, you can just recompile `test.c` instead of having to recompile `foo.c` along with it.

Hope this makes some sense :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile several files in gcc, use:

```
gcc f1.c f2.c ... fn.c -o output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
YES the second way is more preferred.

Long answer:
In this specific case you will get the same result.
To have a dipper understanding you need first to know that "#include" statement basically copy the file it's include and put its value instead of the "#include" statement.
Therefore "h" files are used for forward declaration which you have no problem several different file will include.
while "c" files have the implementations, in that case if both files will implement the same function you will have error in linking them.
Lets say you would have "test2.c" and you will also include foo.c and try to link it with the test.c you will have two implementations of foo.c. But if you only include foo.h in all 3 files (foo.c, test.c and test2.c) you can still link them cause foo.h shouldn't have any implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to include .c files.

In your case
Include foo.h in both test.c and foo.c , but add this inside your header file

```
#ifndef foo.h 
#define foo.h

..your header code here


#endif
```

Writing the header the above way , ensures that you can include it multiple times , just to be on the safe side.

Coming to how you must put your code in files>

> In foo.h

You place all your global structures ,and variables along with function prototypes , that you will use.

> In foo.c

Here you define your modular functions

> In test.c

Here you generally have your main() , and you will call and test the functions defined in foo.c

You Generally put all the files in the same folder , and the compiler will find them and compile them individually , they will be connected later by the linker.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc f1.c f2.c ... fn.c -o output_file
```